# Interface Implementation and Casting in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, casting

I'm facing a conceptual challenge with interfaces in `C#`. As I understand, interfaces act as contracts, and any class that implements an interface agrees to adhere to that contract. Given this, I'm puzzled about why I can't cast an instance of an interface to any class that implements it.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyString { get; set; }
    int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA: IMyInterface
{
    public string MyString { get; set; } = null!;
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : IMyInterface
{
    public string MyString { get; set; } = null!;
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public class CastTest
{
    public static void TestCast(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        CastAgain((ClassB)myInterface);
    }

    private static void CastAgain(ClassB myInterface)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }
}

// Example usage
CastTest.TestCast(new ClassA());
```

When executing `CastTest.TestCast(new ClassA());`, an `InvalidCastException` occurs. My understanding was that since ClassA and ClassB both implement IMyInterface, I should be able to cast an instance of `IMyInterface` to either `ClassA` or `ClassB`.

Could someone explain what I'm missing here? Is my understanding of interfaces and casting incorrect? How should I approach this if I want to work with different classes that implement the same interface?

Comment: You can't cast a dog to a hyena even though both implement the IBark interface. Implementing an interface doesn't mean that a class has *only* the members in that interface either. If `ClassB` has a `Name` property or `Capitalize()` method, what would you expect to happen when you tried to cast `ClassA` which has neither?

Comment: *"why I can't cast an instance of an interface to any class that implements it"* - A car and a boat both have "driveable" interfaces.  But trying to use a car on the water or a boat on the land won't work.  Just because two things implement the same interface doesn't mean they are the same thing or interchangeable in any way.

Comment: In fact, the (perceived) need to cast an interface to a concrete type is a red flag that _may_ signal a design flaw to you. (I am _not_ saying it _never_ makes sense. Just not usually.)

Comment: You can certainly write code to perform the cast and the compiler won't complain, but it would help if you understood what a cast actually is. When you cast a reference as a particular type, you are saying that you guarantee that the object referred to at run time will be that type. A cast is not magic. It doesn't change anything about the object. It simply uses a reference of a different type to refer to it. Have you heard the expression "to cast something in a different light"? It means to look at something in a different way. That's how casting works in programming.

Comment: When you create an instance of a type then that instance is always that type - it never changes. Casting it to an interface or super-type of that class does not change its type. It just gives you a different view of the object. There is no way that a `ClassA` instance is ever a `ClassB` type in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast up the chain to a less specific implementation (ie: from ClassB or ClassA to IMyInterface), but you have to check the specific type of an instance of IMyInterface before you can cast to it.

```cs
var a  = new ClassA();

var i  = (IMyInterface)a; // works (going up the type chain)

var aFromI = i as ClassA; // works (going back to more specific instance)

var bFromI = i as ClassB; // would be null as underlying instance is not ClassB
```

NOTE: the `<variable> as <TYPE>` syntax is shorthand for a type check and cast. The following statements are identical to the `i as ClassA` line above.

```cs
ClassA aFromI = null;

if (i.GetType() is ClassA) {
    aFromI = (ClassA)i;
}
```

Comment: Also note you can do `if ( i is ClassA a ) // use 'a' here`

Comment: Those statements are not identical to `i as ClassA`. If we had `class ClassC : ClassA { }`, and `i` referenced an instance of `ClassC`, then `i as ClassA` would cast & assign `aFromI` correctly, but `i.GetType() is ClassA` would evaluate to false, and not assign to `aFromI`. `if (typeof(ClassA).IsAssigableFrom(i.GetType()))` is semantically closer.

Comment: "_but you have to check the specific type of an instance of IMyInterface before you can cast to it._" -> This is simply not true. You can try to downcast any variable, so long as the cast is theoretically possible. Your examples that use `as` simply return null rather than throwing an `InvalidCastException`, which may or may not be desirable in any given scenario.